# Mercurial convert with --branchmap : converting branch names containing spaces

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

I'm using `hg convert` to clean up the mess in some hg repositories. In the process I'm using the `--branchmap` option to rename some branches.

The problem is, branches with a space in the name (`a b`) don't get renamed. I tried enclosing them in quotes (as seems to work with `--filemap`) or escaping with a backslash, but to no result.

How can I rename the branches with spaces in their names?

Comment: In your " a b" example is there a leading space the one causing the problem? Or only the space between a and b?

Answer (score 0):

Just [do nothing](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2326) for escaping original branchname. Tested with fresh Mercurial (THG) 5.0.2

Original repo

```
>hg branches
My Branch                      4:a44473442f4c
Other Branch                   3:139a43f9edc4
default                        0:356bf10ef7f0 (inactive)
```

Branchmap

```
My Branch My
Other Branch Other
```

Converted repo

```
>hg branches
My                             4:1f22df1c3744
Other                          3:6a2a18b56a5c
default                        0:356bf10ef7f0 (inactive)
```