# Convert mercurial branches into bookmarks while migrating to git

Tags: git, mercurial, git-bash, xargs, hg-git

I am trying to migrate a mercurial repo to git while using hg-git. I follow the tutorial [here](https://androidcalculator.com/migrating-from-mercurial-to-git/) and I stumbled on an issue in the migration step when I push to the git repo. Some branches (who where converted to bookmarks) aren't migrated because they have spaces in their names.

So my solution to that is just to create bookmarks without spaces, I do it with this command (from git bash in win10 x64):

```
$ hg branches -T {branch}\\n | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/g;p;s/ /_/g;s/"//g' | xargs -d \\n -L 2 sh -c 'hg bookmark -r $0 $1_migrate'
```

But this fails with the following error:

```
hg: parse error at 1: unterminated string
("BTSR
  ^ here)
xargs: sh: exited with status 255; aborting
```

However, if I replace the bookmark command with echo, the output seems ok:

```
$ hg branches -T {branch}\\n | sed -e 's/.*/"&"/g;p;s/ /_/g;s/"//g' | xargs -d \\n -L 2 sh -c 'echo $0 $1_migrate'
"BTSR UF2" BTSR_UF2_migrate
```

So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I must be doing something wrong with xargs I presume, but what?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can't find a fix for your immediate issue you could rename the branches -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416362/mercurial-convert-with-branchmap-converting-branch-names-containing-spaces

Comment: @StayOnTarget thanks for the info, however renaming with --branchmap seems manual work. Although you could create the file automatically, I was afraid just stumbling with the spaces problem again but in another situation.

Comment: Branchmap would be OK if you only had to do this one time. But if its a repeated process I agree, that is not ideal at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stumbling with the spaces problem, I tried to find an alternative solution. Instead of bookmarking a branch by name, I bookmark it now by rev which circumvents the spaces problem:

```
$ hg branches -c -T {rev}\\n{branch}\\n | sed -e "s/ /_/g" | xargs -t -d \\n -L 2 sh -c 'hg bookmark -r $0 $1_migrate'
```

If anyone knows the solution to the spaces problem, I would really like to know it. But I can live happily with this workaround.